# Return value from social media connect in wordpress

Tags: c#, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, twitter, windows-phone

I want to create a mobile version of a website my friend built with WordPress. I am currently developing for Windows Phone.

I want to know what value is returned when I log in using Social Media (Facebook / Twitter). Because when I try to register using social media, I look at my profile and I didn't need to input my password. My friend used [userpro plugin](http://userproplugin.com) for connect to social media. I want my application to be used for commenting using that social media.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably logged in to Facebook / Twitter on your smartphone, and selected "Remember Me", so you don't have to input your password each and everytime you log in.

Also, in my experience, wordpress mobile `REQUIRES` you to check remember me when logging in via Social Media.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Well. I do try use my web browser on my notebook and it directly logged in. Anyway my problem is I can't get password to log in to my wordpress so I am having difficult for add comment

Comment: In wordpress admin (yoursite.com/wp-admin) you can assign a password to users that logged in through social media. I use this, and log in to admin panel via FaceBook, and have an app on my phone that requires password.

Comment: My friend want his wordpress stay simple which means anyone who logged in on his site didn't need to create password to log in and then user can keep log in use his social media without use any password.

Comment: This is no problem, but if the users want to use the app, they are required to check the "Stay logged in" checkbox

Comment: But I can't use add comment feature because I need to send user password to XMLRPC but I can't find any user password